# R: specifying color for different facets / panels in lattice

Tags: r, graph, lattice

My data is as follows:

```
grp = rep(1:2, each = 100)
chr = c(rep(1:10, each = 10), rep(1:10, each = 10))
var = paste (grp, "chr", chr, sep = "")
pos = (rep(1:10, 20)) 
yvar = rnorm(200) 
mydf = data.frame (var, pos, yvar)

require( lattice)
xyplot(yvar ~ pos| factor(var), data = mydf, layout = c(1,10), type = c("g", "h"),
         col = "darkolivegreen", lwd = 4)
```

(1) I want to put different colors to alternate graph / panel - for example - `2chr1` is darkolive green but `chr10` is say purple. then  again dark olive green and purple so on.

(2) I want to use reverse order of graph means that `2chr9` is at the bottom.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I think the subplots are called "panels" in `lattice`-world and "facets" in `ggplot`-world ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `as.table=TRUE` to change the order of panels and `groups` (along with an extended `col` vec) to change colo(u)rs.

**edit**: adjusted order of factor levels

```
mydf <- 
  data.frame (var, pos, yvar, 
              ##  fvar = factor(var,levels=unique(var)),
              fvar = factor(var, levels = c(outer(2:1, 1:10, paste, sep="chr"))))

xyplot(yvar ~ pos| fvar,
       groups=fvar,
       data = mydf, layout = c(1,10,2), type = c("g", "h"),
       col = c("darkolivegreen","purple"), lwd = 4, as.table=TRUE)
```

The extended `layout` command gives two pages.

[image]

Alternatively, a side-by-side layout might be nice:

```
library(latticeExtra)
useOuterStrips(xyplot(yvar ~ pos|factor(grp)*factor(chr),
                      groups=grp,
                      col=c("darkolivegreen","purple"),
                      data = mydf, layout = c(2,10), type = c("g", "h"),
                      lwd = 4, as.table=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: @ Ben, thanks, AS.TABLE works but the col doesnot produce what I intend to do. I did not want to put different color to alternative values rather to alternate panel ...

Comment: ?? I thought that's what my solution did.  Is the picture (just added) not what you wanted?  (Did you forget the `groups` specification?)

Comment: The sensible layout I want is 1Chr1 follows 2chr2, 1chr2, follow 2chr2....and so on ....

Comment: The comment doesn't make perfect sense to me.  I interpret it as 2chr2, 1chr1, 2chr2, 1chr2 ... maybe you meant 2chr1, 1chr1, 2chr2, 1chr2 ...  (more sensible but I still don't see why 2chr* would precede 1chr*

Comment: Each grp = 1:2, should be grouped for each level of chr, although myintension was to combined them to make a single name like var = paste (grp, "chr", chr, sep = "")

Comment: See revised code above (you can change `2:1` to `1:2` in the `outer` statement if that order makes more sense)